# Check for key in hash maps while checking user input

Tags: java

I am trying to compare the key values of a hashmap with user input but I'm not sure of what approach should be taken.

This is the current code I have:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type an instruction from the list \n 1. hello \n 2. goodbye");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    HashMap helloMap = new HashMap<>();
    helloMap.put("hello", "you typed hello");

    HashMap goodbyeMap = new HashMap<>();
    goodbyeMap.put("goodbe", "you typed goodbye");


    if(input.equals(helloMap)){

        String helloOutput = (String) helloMap.get("hello");
        System.out.println(helloOutput);

    }
    else if (input.equals(goodbyeMap)){
        String goodbyeOutput = (String) goodbyeMap.get("goodbye");
        System.out.println(goodbyeOutput);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
```

The issue that I've ran into is that when I try to use this program it always defaults to the else clause and this is because I'm used to using .equals to compare it to a String value but I know this is different! Does anyone know the solution for this? **Ok so I found a solution for it...** It works but is it good enough?

```
 String goodbyeCommand = String.valueOf(goodbyeMap.keySet()).replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").trim();

 String helloCommand = String.valueOf(helloMap.keySet()).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

You are comparing the input `String` with the `HashMap` object. `String` object is not equal to `HashMap` object, which is why the boolean expression is always false.

#### The solution

Please have a look at the following sample:

```
Map<String, String> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
outputMap.put("hello", "you typed hello");
outputMap.put("goodbye", "you typed goodbye");

System.out.println("Type an instruction from the list \n 1. hello \n 2. goodbye");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();

String output = outputMap.get(input);
if (output == null) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
} else {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

#### Breakdown

1. We define a `Map<String, String>` containing the program's response mapped to predefined user inputs.
2. We ask the user for input. When you are done using `Scanner`, it is good practice to close it by calling `.close()`.
3. We retrieve the response from the map based on the user input.
4. We check for `null`: if it is `null`, it means the user input was not a valid key for `outputMap`.
5. Print the result.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to compare to the actual element of your map instead of the map itself:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type an instruction from the list \n 1. hello \n 2. goodbye");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    HashMap helloMap = new HashMap<>();
    helloMap.put("hello", "you typed hello");

    HashMap goodbyeMap = new HashMap<>();
    goodbyeMap.put("goodbe", "you typed goodbye");


    if(input.equals(helloMap.get("hello"))){

        String helloOutput = (String) helloMap.get("hello");
        System.out.println(helloOutput);

    }
    else if (input.equals(goodbyeMap.get("goodbe"))){
        String goodbyeOutput = (String) goodbyeMap.get("goodbye");
        System.out.println(goodbyeOutput);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
```

Comment: I would be happy to know why is this answer considered to be unhelpful.